# Cannot setup SSRS datasource

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi

We are running a local PowerBI report server.   It displays PowerBI reports just fine.    I wanted to add a datasource to it so that we can also use it for SSRS reporting.    Everytime we attempt to create a datasource, it throws this error:

> Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010+MissingEndpointException: The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. --->

The backend SQL database is 2019.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the SSRS feature installed on the backend server? Is the SSRS Service running? Does the SSRS Configuration Manager have the web services enabled? Is there a (trusted) certificate configured for the HTTPS side of its web service? Do Windows firewalls allow access to it via http/https (TCP ports 80 and 443) from the Power BI machine?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/849749ac-b387-4f99-ac83-aec4c1ef0b95/cannot-create-new-data-source-on-ssrs-2016?forum=sqlreportingservices  Also note there the location of the log file you should be able to find the error details and post those.